# Asynchronus Intellisense in Visual Studio Code | NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I often write modules that are asynchronous, and due to their asynchronous nature I will require, resolve, and then assign these modules during some initialization code. For example:

```js
var asynchronousModule;


function doSomethingUsingMyLoadedModule() {
    // Ideally intellisense would be able to do its thing for asynchronousModule right here
    asynchronousModule._doSomething();
}


// initializer
(async () => {
    asynchrousModule = await require('my-custom-async-module');
})();
```

However, because `asynchronousModule` isn't assigned until after the `doSomethingUsingMyLoadedModule` function is declared, intellisense can't auto-complete/auto-populate `asynchronousModule` within that function.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to explicitly tell intellisense to *prematurely* assign a value to our variable at declaration time, using inline-comments or some such. For example, something like this on the first line:

```js
var asynchronousModule; // vsc-intellisense assign-async-import my-custom-async-module
```

That'd be awesome, but probably wishful thinking. However, perhaps there's still some other way of leveraging intellisense for async modules *without* having to wrap my entire file in an async function? By that I mean re-writing my code to something like this:

```js
(async () => {
    const asynchrousModule = await require('my-custom-async-module');

    function doSomethingUsingMyLoadedModule() {
        asynchrousModule._doSomething();
    }
})();
```

While this would allow intellisense to work, and it actually looks nice in this example, I really don't like having the contents of an entire file tabbed over, especially as files get bigger, so it's not my ideal solution.

Comment: why do you need `await require('my-custom-async-module');`, what is the use of the `await`

Comment: @rioV8 The module is asynchronous, and so it returns a promise. As such, I need the await in order to have the promise resolve. As an example use case, maybe my module establishes and then holds onto a DB connection so I can reuse this same connection across multiple files. Because establishing a DB connection is asynchronous, the module exports a promise which will resolve into that DB connection. So resolving the promise, either via await or via promise.then is necessary to get the actual useful portion of the module.

Comment: do the handling of the promise inside the `_doSomething()` function. The module should be written that the export does not contain a Promise. Don't make the DB connection while loading the module but inside the functions that need it, cache the result of a DB connection

Comment: @rioV8 This would work, but I don't think it's optimal. Assume my module is synchronous now but its only purpose is to expose and cache a shared DB connection via its only method, `_doSomething()`. Though the connection is cached after its first call, `_doSomething()` would still return a promise on subsequent calls (or else I would constantly have to check its return type). Though the overhead of awaiting a single already-resolved promise is negligible, now imagine it for a chain of dependent modules built this way, each one awaiting the already-resolved promise of the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first asked this question, I was a naïve developer who didn't understand how much TypeScript I was actually using when writing JSDoc-esque syntax for IntelliSense in my editor. But now, as a much wiser developer a month and change later, I have an answer to this.

*Note that I'm **not** necessarily saying* it's a great idea to override your module's export object with a promise, but doing so worked for me in the past, and at the very least I can use the following to provide accurate IntelliSense for legacy code:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @typedef  {T extends Promise<infer Value> ? Value : T} PromiseValue
 */

/** @type {PromiseValue<import('my-custom-async-module')>} */
var asynchronousModule;
```

The `@typedef` tag declares the type `PromiseValue` which we use to extract what a promise resolves to. Then with the `@type` tag, we import the asynchronous module and wrap it in our `PromiseValue` utility to extract its resolved object.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
const asynchrousModule = require('my-custom-async-module');

function doSomethingUsingMyLoadedModule() {
    asynchrousModule._doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I explain in my reply to your comment on my OP, this wouldn’t work as it’s an asynchronous module, meaning the module returns a promise which would later resolve into an object with our _doSomething method.